# Sorting Algorithm in c using pointers

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

It seems that when sorting, insertion-sort would be more time-efficient then quick-sort when sorting a linkedlist. Is this true and why? thanks. Also do you guys know any website where I can practice my programming skill etc. thanks.

Comment: you are asking two questions

Comment: Do a web search using the search words "online judge" to find numerous sites with programming challenges.

Comment: Given a singly linked list, I wouldn't use *either* insertion-sort or quick-sort; I'd use merge-sort, which lends itself *very* nicely to linked-list sorting in constant space.

Answer (score 0):

I think that insertion-sort would be much faster then quick-sort when sorting a linkedlist.